# Why is my Akka WebSocket Actor disconnecting/dying?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka, actor

(Update/fix at bottom) I'm using the PlayFramework 2.x to create a simple WebSocket application using an actor. I'm able to get things working (sending echo ping) but I'm just wondering why the WebSocket disconnects after a short amount of time (roughly 30 seconds) if nothing is sent or received? I have a long-running (5-20 minute) process that I need to use the websocket to send back the notification when it ends.

I put a postStop to see if the actor is stopping and that is indeed hit. Maybe I just don't understand the actor lifecycle? I can't find anything in the docs on why an actor would be killed off in this case as there isn't a parent actor.

Controller:

```
public WebSocket socket() {
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(request ->
            ActorFlow.actorRef(
                    WebSocketActor::props,
                    actorSystem, materializer
            )
    );
}
```

Actor

```
public class WebSocketActor extends AbstractActor {
public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
    return Props.create(WebSocketActor.class, out);
}

private final ActorRef out;

public WebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
    this.out = out;
    ActorSystem actorSystem = context().system();
}

@Override
public Receive createReceive() {

    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(String.class, message ->
                    out.tell("Message: " + message, self())
            )
   }

public void postStop() {
    System.out.println("I'm dying over here!");
}

}
```

UPDATE: Thanks @chunjef. I did, in fact, have to set the idle-timeout, but also had to start in production mode as some application.config values are not used in dev mode. Why they set it up like this I have no idea and is very frustrating. Per the official documentation:

> Note: In dev mode, when you use the run command, your
>   application.conf settings will not be picked up by the server. This is
>   because in dev mode the server starts before the application classpath
>   is available. There are several other options you’ll need to use
>   instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the actor's lifecycle is tied to the WebSocket connection: when the connection is closed, Play automatically stops the actor. And your connection is closing because it's inactive for too long.

From the Akka HTTP [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/java/http/server-side/websocket-support.html) (Akka HTTP is the underlying engine in Play):

> Inactive WebSocket connections will be dropped according to the [idle-timeout settings](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/java/http/common/timeouts.html#idle-timeouts). In case you need to keep inactive connections alive, you can either tweak your idle-timeout or inject ‘keep-alive’ messages regularly.

You can change the `idle-timeout` settings as described in the above link or change the equivalent Play settings described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsAkkaHttp) (the Play settings will override the Akka HTTP settings). For example, to completely disable the timeout via the Play configuration:

```
idleTimeout = infinite
```